# Loading csv file into chart.js

Tags: javascript, csv, chart.js

I would like to load a csv file to be used as the data for my chart.js file but I'm having trouble loading it. If my csv file is within the same directory as my main js script file how would i go about loading it?

Comment: You can put the file in `public` dir instead of the same directory as main.js, if it is possible.

Comment: ok if i were to put it in the ```public``` directory, how do i now load my csv file into chart.js?

Comment: You can use `d3-fetch` to achieve that. I am adding an extended answer for the same. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [d3-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-fetch) to get the csv data, assuming the csv file is in `public` directory present in project root directory:

```js
import { csv } from "d3-fetch";

function fetchData() {
    return csv('/filename.csv').then((data) => (data));
}

export default fetchData;
```

You can use `await` to get results from fetch data, or use `then` to get data when fetch is resolved.

```js
let data = await fetchData();
```

```js
let chartDataHolder;
fetchData.then((result) => {
   chartDataHolder = result; 
});
```

Hope this helps.